# Returned canonical ID gives me MismatchSenderId

Tags: android, sdk, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app, that uses two different SDK's (A and B), where each SDK wants to use GCM to send push notifications to the device. I am also responsible for SDK A. The main problem is, that after some time, push notifications for A do not arrive at the device anymore and I do not know why.

We suspect, that it has something to do with the following issue: Currently, SDK A successfully uses the deprecated `gcm.register(senderID)` method to retrieve its `registrationID`. B uses the recommended way with  `instanceID.getToken(SenderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null)` to get its registrationID (also called push token). All of this works fine. I get two different tokens and push notifications arrive.

The registrationID for A looks like this `APA91bFRLo_AqvWY9M6Xqc_s2pqxS09LhpSd0pO3...`

The registrationID for B like this `dxhUcxJ-IpE:APA91bHG19a107E6DU_iGPCZm0mjd7FBH5ciGgtG...`

When I try to send a push notification for SDK A by hand using curl (like [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http)), the push notification arrives at the device and the call returns:

```
{
    "multicast_id":7932847...,
    "success":1,
    "failure":0,
    "canonical_ids":1,
    "results":
        [{"registration_id":"dxhUcxJ-IpE:APA91bHG19a107E6DU_iGPCZm0mjd4F..."}]
}
```

As far as I understood from the Google documentation, this means that for all further calls, I should replace my current registrationID from A with the one returned in the results-array. The point is, that the canonical id perfectly matches the registrationID for SDK B. When I now try to execute the same curl call for SDK A with the "canonical-ID", the server returns `"error":"MismatchSenderId"`.

This makes sense, as only SDK B is registered for this registrationID. Can anyone explain, why I still get this canonical id, whether I should use it and if someone experienced similar issues when integrating two Push-SDKs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error seems to suggest that the two SDKs are registering different Sender IDs. Are you sure that both SDKs are using the same Sender ID?

Comment: No, both SDK do in fact use different Sender IDs. Is that a problem? Should they use the same senderID?

Comment: Having multiple sender ids is OK I think that the issue is having multiple instance id tokens for the same app install.

Comment: [This description](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en#receiving-messages-from-multi-senders) confirms that GCM supports multiple senders and that the client must fetch a registration ID/token for each.  You indicate you use two sender IDs. Am I right that you then have an API Key for each? And during your testing with `curl` you are taking care to use the right key for the registration ID/token?  The [description of error responses](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) explains "Mismatched Sender".

Comment: Both SDK have their separate API Key, but I only have access to the one for SDK A. SDK B is developed by an external company.
I am not sure what you mean by your last assumption, but as I stated above: I basically use the same curl command and just substituted the previous RegistrationID with the new one ( the canonical ID) from the response. This gives me the error. I am aware what this means and in some way I understands why I get it (SDK B has this registrationID), but why does Google return it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using 2 different SDKs.

SDK A here is using the non-recommended method gcm.register(senderID). One of the reasons why Google recommends using the [Instance Id API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation) is because, this API provides a listener that listens for any token refreshs and requests that your app refreshes its tokens. This will ensure your app always has the latest token.

Now with SDK A, you are pushing with an old registration token, which will work, but eventually will stop working when GCM removes the old token from their server. 
With SDK B, you have the latest token.

**Once you send a push notification, you will get in your response the latest registration token known as the [canonical id](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#canonical-ids). Your server side should update the old registraton token with this canonical id.**

Why you get a MismatchSenderId error:

> A registration token is tied to a certain group of senders. When a client app registers for GCM, it must specify which senders are allowed to send messages. You should use one of those sender IDs when sending messages to the client app. If you switch to a different sender, the existing registration tokens won't work.

I suppose, SDK A and SDK B has its own sender id, which explains why that returned token is not working for SDK A.

Workaround:-

- For SDK A, try registering that device again when you will get the latest token which you could use to push.
- Better still, implement the Instance Id API

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. So one possibility, as you say, is to re-register SDK with the `canonicalID`, which is the same as the `registrationID` for SDK B? As you suspected, SDK A and B use different senderIDs. I will try to update the answer, but we just updated our SDK to use the `InstanceID` API, which solved our problems.

Comment: Yea, the best solution was to implement the Instance Id API. If that is not done, i assume, this particular problem could have been solved by re-registering. Anyway, glad i could help.. Cheers :)